# Does casting Contingency via Wish remove the requirement to carry a statuette?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, wish

When used to cast another spell, Wish states:

> You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly Components.

(PHB 288)
Contingency states:

> ...contingency ends on you if its material component is ever not on your person.

(PHB 227)
Does this mean that, when cast via Wish, you are always considered to have the statuette on you?

Comment: Related on [material requirements for spells cast through Wish](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59620/how-does-the-wish-spell-work-with-spells-that-interact-with-material-components) - but Contigency is different with regard to it's particular Material Component.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## There is no statuette so the requirement is always met

*Wish* removes the need for any requirements including material components for spells.

> You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly Components.

Note that it doesn't say that *wish* gives you any spell components that you are missing, just that the requirements no longer apply. This is the same as spell restrictions based on class, for example. If the Bard wants to cast a warlock spell using *wish* they can do so and the spell doesn't magically make them a warlock for it to happen. The spell simply requires nothing for you to perform when using *wish*.

*Contingency* normally requires a statuette of yourself worth at least 1500 gp and ends if the statuette which was used as a material component for the spell is ever apart from you:

> ...contingency ends on you if **its material component** is ever not on
> your person.

However, because you cast with *wish* there was no material component (statuette). That requirement was completely waived by *wish*. Thus, the requirement simply does not apply.  And thus, it essentially is treated as if the statuette was always on your person.