# If a Contingency spell has been cast on a creature, does the Simulacrum spell transfer the contingent spell to its duplicate?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, simulacrum

Simple premise: If I cast *simulacrum* on an entity that has a *contingency* spell cast on it, does that contingency transfer to the simulacrum?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Even if it did, it would end immediately

From my interpretation of game design, it probably shouldn't. But even if it did, the way I read both spells, the effect of contingency would immediately end. The reasoning is as follows.

The Contingency spell requires a specific material component, which is "(A statuette of yourself carved from ivory and decorated with gems worth at least 1,500 gp)". Additionally, the spell has a special ending condition linked to this material:

> Also, contingency ends on you if its material component is ever not on your person.

Assuming the contingency would be linked to the simulacrum (not to the original person), it would require another statuette *in possession of the simulacrum*. However, Simulacrum states:

> It appears to be the same as the original, but it has half the creature's hit point maximum and is formed without any equipment.

Although equipment does not refer to all gear, it should be fair to assume that the simulacrum does not create a copy of the 1500 gp statuette (otherwise you could use it to duplicate non-equipment items, which would be awkward). Therefore, as the simulacrum does not possess the required statuette, the contingency spell ends.

Comment: Even though this answers the specific question adequately, it might be good to address the more general issue of whether spells affecting the target of *Simulacrum* are copied.

Comment: @RyanThompson I preferred to answer this way because it is a very clear and unambiguous answer directly from the rules. Honestly, I am not sure about the answer for the general question (which, being fair, might be a different question). My instincts say "no", as a DM I say "no", but I can't really make a case based on the rules for it.

Comment: I prefer this answer too. I would personally rule that any spell affecting the simulacrum-creature affects the sim, so long as the requirements are still met. However, not having a statuette makes perfect sense for why a contingency wouldn't transfer. Thank you!

Comment: This makes me wonder if there are any items similar to the Ring of Spell Storing, or other means, that could get around the component requirement for higher level spells like this. And if so, how that interacts with *contingency*. I might post it as a question...

Comment: Aha, [someone else asked the same thing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123019/does-casting-contingency-via-wish-remove-the-requirement-to-carry-a-statuette). TL;DR, _Wish_ can get around it, requiring no material component and it would still work. While it's an edge case, it might be worth putting that into your answer, since there's a way for the statuette to not be required.